# "[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:]" sometimes returns nil

Tags: ios

I'm trying to retrieve some `URLs` from the `infoDictionary`. 9 times out of 10, the `URLs` are returned correctly. However, very occasionally, the `URLs` will return nil. Any idea what might be causing this behavior?

`[NSBundle mainBundle]` and `[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary]` are both not nil when this strange behavior occurs. Only the `URLs` return nil.

Comment: `NSLog(@"infoDictionary: %@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary]);` to see what is there. But you are not trying to save into the application bundle, are you, that is not possible in iOS.

Comment: @Zaph I didn't write this code, so I'm trying to figure out myself how these URLs are being stored in the infoDictionary in the first place. When I NSLog the infoDictionary, I don't see the keys for the URLs. The URL keys are absent regardless of whether the URLs are returned correctly or not.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS it is not possible to write to the app bundle so trying to do so will fail. Typically data is written to and read from a file in the app's document directory which can be obtained as follows:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths firstObject];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:myFileName];
```